# Tetration of a number giving a complex number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, tetration

Giving this power equation:
$$S=\lim_{n\to\infty} {^n}x=-i$$
where the symbol $^nx$ means the tetration operator, we can write in a form not formally correct:
$${\ ^{n}x = \ \atop {\ }} {{\underbrace{x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^{x}}}}}} \atop \infty}$$ which must be equal to $-i$.
So we can write $x^{-i}=-i$ and then $x=\exp \left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi\right)$

For $k=0$ we have: $x=\exp(\pi/2)\simeq 4.81$. So: this means:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} {^n4.81}=-i$$
But also, for $k=2$, we can write $\lim_{n\to\infty}{^n}2575.9=-i$

This means:
putting: $a=\exp\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi\right)$
$${\ \atop {\ }} {{\underbrace{a^{a^{\cdot^{\cdot^{a}}}}}} \atop \infty}=-i$$

If we change $-i$ with $i$, we found the same result. 
Is this a correct result? Thanks

Comment: $4.81^z$ has a repelling fixed point near $z=\pm i$  So if you iterate the logarithm base $\approx$ 4.81 an infinite number of times, then you would get to $\pm i$.

It is probably off topic, but if you implement Kneser's real valued tetration solution in the complex plane, then the tet(z) function will tend towards the two fixed point conjugates respectively in the upper/lower halves of the complex plane as $|\Im(z)|$ gets arbitrarily large.